# Is there a method for parallel frequency sources sum where individual sources do not contain the total sum mode?

Tags: fourier-analysis

This question lies in between physics/engineering and maths, so apologies if this is the wrong place to post.

As the title indicates, I am looking for a method where I can generate total frequency modes that are a sum of individual sources oscillating at different, individual frequencies. The main point here is that the individual sources cannot contain the frequency mode that is seen as the total sum of all. The individual sources can be considered are fully controllable for the purposes of the excercise.

A bit of background, the total mode of oscillation at a node, that is the sum of individual parallel sources, is an eigenfrequency of the individual sources, and that creates problems.

I have tried several techniques such as "slicing" the signal in each of the sources (e.g. one produces the first have of a sine and the next the second half) and summing but this still means that I have the frequency showing on each of the sources when i do my FFT.

thanks in advance.